# Using getattr to work with a method from another class

Tags: python, python-2.7

pI am working on a bit of code that does nothing important, but one of the things I am trying to make it do is call a function from another class, and the class name is pulled out of a list and put into a variable. Mind you I have literally just learned python over the last 2 weeks, and barely know my way around how to program.

What I believe that this should do is when getattr() is called, it will pass the attribute 'run_question' that is contained in the respective class with the same name as what is in question_type, and then pass it onto 'running_question'. I know there are probably better ways to do what I am attempting, but I want to know why *this* method doesn't work how I think it should.

```
 #! /usr/bin/python
 rom random import randrange

 class QuestionRunner(object):
     def __init__(self):
         ##initialize score to zero
         self.score = 0
         ##initialize class with the types of questions
         self.questiontypes = ['Addition', 'Subtraction', 'Division', 'Multiplication']
     ##randomly selects question type from self.questiontypes list    
     def random_type(self):
         type = self.questiontypes[randrange(0, 4)]
         return type
     ##question function runner, runs question function from self
     def run_questions(self):
         try:
             question_type = self.random_type()
             running_question = getattr(question_type, 'run_question' )
         except AttributeError:
             print question_type
             print "Attribute error:Attribute not found"
         else: running_question()

 class Question(object):
     pass 


 class Multiplication(Question):
     def  run_question(self):
         print "*" 

 class Division(Question):
     def run_question(self):
         print "/"

 class Subtraction(Question):
     def run_question(self):
         print "-"

 class Addition(Question):
     def run_question(self):
         print "+"



 test = QuestionRunner()

 test.run_questions()
```

This outputs:

```
[david@leonid mathtest] :( $  python mathtest.py  
Division
Attribute error:Attribute not found
[david@leonid mathtest] :) $
```

Which indicates that I am not getting the run_question attribute as I expect.

I should note that when I put the functions into the QuestionRunner class in the following way, everything works as expected. The main reason I am using classes where it really isn't needed it to actually get a good grasp of how to make them do what I want.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
from random import randrange

class QuestionRunner(object):
    def __init__(self):
        ##initialize score to zero
        self.score = 0
        ##initialize class with the types of questions
        self.questiontypes = ['addition', 'subtraction', 'division', 'multiplication']
    ##randomly selects question type from self.questiontypes list    
    def random_type(self):
        type = self.questiontypes[randrange(0, 4)]
        return type
    ##question function runner, runs question function from self
    def run_questions(self):
        try:
            question_type = self.random_type()
            running_question = getattr(self, question_type)
        except AttributeError:
            exit(1)
        else: running_question()


    def  multiplication(self):
        print "*"


    def division(self):
        print "/"


    def addition(self):
        print "+"


    def subtraction(self):
        print "-"




test = QuestionRunner()

test.run_questions()
```

Any help on why this isn't working would be great, and I appreciate it greatly.

Any help on why this isn't working would be great, and I appreciate it greatly.

Comment: Side note: not as many people follow the version-specific tags ("python-2.7" has ~260) as follow the general "python" tag (25.4k), so you tend to get more attention when you include "python" as well.

Comment: tl;dr. http://sscce.org/

Comment: -1 Can you post your real code and output? `Attribute error:Attribute not found` is definitely made up. Real output shows a traceback, a proper exception name and message.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I have found out the missing concept that was causing my logic to be faulty. I assumed that I could pass the *name* of an object to getattr, when in reality I have to pass the object itself.

Comment: Instead of using `getattr` at all, you could store the questions themselves, i.e. `self.questions = [Addition(), Subtraction(), Division(), Multiplication()]`, and then `random.choice(self.questions()).run_question()` would suffice.  In practice I'd give the result of the choice a name, but the key point is that you don't need to use `getattr` to get access to the method `run_question`, `.run_question` suffices if you have the question object.